# how to make the docker run command-line shorter for the user?

Tags: linux, docker

I've uploaded the (hypothetical) program `dhprog` to Docker Hub, and it works like this:

```
docker run -v "$PWD:/workdir" -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" --rm -it dhuser/dhimage dhprog arg1 arg2
```

The non-dockerized version of the program works like this:

```
dhprog arg1 arg2
```

I have `-v` because I want to make the current directory available as `/workdir` in the container (so that if `arg1` is a filename outside the container, then `dhprog` in the container can read that file).

I have `-u` because I want to run `dhprog` in the container as non-root, and if `arg2` is an output filename, it should write it to outside the container as the same UID and GID who has invoked the `docker run` command.

How can I make the `docker run` command-line shorter for the user, especially the `-v` and `-u` flags, without compromising the 2 features (reading and writing of files outside the container) and writing files outside of the container as non-root, but as the invoking user?

Comment: How about creating bash aliases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real option here is to distribute a shell script that wraps all of that up for you.  E.g., make a shell script called `dhprog` that looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec docker run -v "$PWD:/workdir" -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
  --rm -it dhuser/dhimage dhprog "$@"
```

I would avoid bash aliases because there are many situations in which those aliases won't be available, while a script in `$PATH` works just like any other binary.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a script with the that "install" your command as a local script inside the user home directory.
2. Publish it online as a plain text page, using a domain you own or inside a repository exposing it via a service like [rawgit](http://rawgit.com).
3. Now you can distribute it with a copy&paste snippet like this:

   curl -s "http://example.com/dhprog" | bash

Today there are many example of this approach, you can see for example the [sdkman installation script](http://get.sdkman.io/) that runs in the same way described above.

4. Now the user will have a `dhprog` available in his shell.
5. Bonus: if you are good at scripting, you can even force the user shell to check for an update of your program (the script) every time a new shell is created (e.g. like oh-my-zsh do).

Answer (score 1):

[Sparrow](https://sparrowhub.org) is quite handy for such a task:

```
$ cat story.bash
 set -e
 path=$(config path)
 docker run -v "$path:/workdir" -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
 --rm -it dhuser/dhimage dhprog \
 $(cli_args)

$ cat sparrow.json
 {
   "name" : "docker-dhprog",
   "version" : "0.0.1"
 } 
$ sparrow plg upload
```

On other server where sparrow is installed, just:

```
$ sparrow plg install docker-dhprog
$ sparrow plg run docker-dhprog --param path=$PWD -- arg1 arg2
```